# How to add text response into custom payload using Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am trying to add text response in the custom payload within Dialogflow but it did not display text response. It only show the button when I integrate the Dialogflow Messenger. How can I fix this problem?

Output:

```
  {
      "richContent": [
        [
          {
            "message" : "To get started, please select the topics you're looking for more info.",
            "type": "chips",
            "options": [
              {
                "text": "Science"
              },
              {
                "text": "Math"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      ]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

By 'Text Response', if you mean the 'message' part of your custom payload code, then it will not display that in Dialogflow Messenger Integration.

Since you are using Dialogflow ES:
The 'Responses' section in Dialogflow ES works in a chronological manner.
You can display your message as well as your suggestion chips.

1. Under Responses, In your Text Response section's first line: write down your message
2. Click on Add Section + Click on Custom Payload
3. Type your rich content code. Follow this link: [Suggestion Chips](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#suggestion_chip_response_type)